# javascript alert in an if else statement not triggering

Tags: javascript, alert

If the first part of the statement fails I am trying to send an alert. But I cannot figure out why the alert is not triggering. Yes, I have forced the statement to fail.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
    {
    if (<?php echo $browser; ?> >= 1)
        {
        var user = $("#ownerPost input").val();
        var oid = <?php echo $Owner; ?>;
            $.ajax(
                    { 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'follow.php', 
                    data: "oid="+oid, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                        {
                        var id = data[0];
                        var name = data[1];
                        $('#output2').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+name);
                        } 
                    }
                    );

        $("#output").html("<b>You are now following: </b>" + user);
        e.preventDefault();
        }
        else
        {
        alert("You must log in to follow");
        }
    }
    );
```

Here is the output from view source:
The actual number is 56 and makes the statement true and that is correct. It is when the statement is false that it will not trigger the else and hence the alert. 
If I place an alert right before the else it will show the alert because first part is true.

```
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
    {if (56 >= 1){
        var user = $("#ownerPost input").val();
        var oid = 56;
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'follow.php', 
            data: "oid="+oid, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var id = data[0];
                var name = data[1];
                $('#output2').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+name);} });
            $("#output").html("<b>You are now following: </b>" + user);
            e.preventDefault();
            }else{alert("You must log in to follow");}});
```

Comment: what's the value of `$browser` ?

Comment: Hmm, under assumption that your **$browser** and **$Owner** variables are integer, I can only think that your *$browser is >= 1*. 
Otherwise, you may have syntax errors - if the variables I mentioned are not integers (or booleans). What is this evaluating to in your browser?

Comment: your brace placement is  confusing

Comment: You need to show us the actual javascript being output, not the php version. You could very well be outputting values without commas, causing this to fail.

Comment: The value of $browser and $Owner are integers I have replaced both vars with integers and it still will not trigger the alert.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error.  I was going to suggest a try/catch, but that will not help with a syntax error.  Please edit your question and put in the "view > page source" as the others have suggested.  Also, can you use Firebug, or equivalent to view the console?

**EDIT:**
I do get the alert with this code.  Note that I set browser to 0.

```
blah = function(e) {
    if (0 >= 1) {
        var user = $("#ownerPost input").val();
        var oid = 56;
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'follow.php',
            data : "oid=" + oid,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                var id = data[0];
                var name = data[1];
                $('#output2')
                .html("<b>id: </b>" + id + "<b> name: </b>" + name);
            }
        });
        $("#output").html("<b>You are now following: </b>" + user);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert("You must log in to follow");
    }
};
blah.call();
```